# How to load Scripts into Cisco Routers

Tags: cisco, automation, scripting

I would like to load scripts automatically based on certain triggers/conditions into cisco routers.

Can anyone provide me a link or tell me how to do it?

what does the scripts does?
1. Once the user authenticate to a NAS(cisco router), it will grab its userID and password. Then, it will do background authentication for the next router the users wish to use.
2. The script also will disconnect a user from NAS/cisco router once his timing ends.

I **am only interested on how to load the scripts into the router automatically.**

I am currently using CISCO ACS for AAA server.
The problem is I am required to do **background authentication** for users that are stored in SQL. 
So, when those users login, their usernames and passwords need to be catched for background authentication.

I need to load the scripts automatically to cisco routers which I am still have no idea on how to do it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this part I have solved my problem.

1. Use Tcl/Expect scripts to do auto-login.
2. Download Active tcl in order to write the script.
3. Download TclODBC package using Teacup that is included when installing Active Tcl.
4. TCLODB is used so that you can read data using Tcl script from temp database/table that is created when a user login to the website
5. Write the expect script to do auto-login.

These are general solution that I am currently using. Many thanks to everyone that have tried to help me :)

Comment: oh another solution is you can use a php script + its php class to do the autologin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Radius or TACACS+ for AuthN/AuthZ? Those will accomplish the same thing as your proposed script, and unlike your script, are well-supported methods by Cisco.

Comment: ah yes I am currently using CISCO ACS for AAA server.
The problem is I am required to do background authentication for users that are stored in SQL. 
So, when those users login, their usernames and passwords need to be catched for background authentication.

I need to load the scripts automatically to cisco routers which I am still have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can help I think we need the question clarified...do you mean that you want some kind of 'single sign on cookie' for your routers, where a user logs into one router and then can ssh into other routers without authenticating?

Just food for thought, on Linux boxes you could get away with something like this using a passworded pre-shared SSH key... once the user types the SSH private key password, they can use that pre-shared SSH key to log in to a number of Linux boxes without having to re-authenticate.

I've never tried to set up pre-shared keys on Cisco devices though... I'll have to Google it (assuming I'm describing your problem accurately)

Comment: You got it almost there! But, the user will only key in his own username and password that is stored in SQL server. Not the shared secret key, etc. Hope that clarifies your question.